# Script for sending a header to netcat

Tags: bash

I work [with a protocol](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Manager+Interface+%28AMI%29) that's easy to use simply with [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/). The protocol starts with a login message, so I thought I could bang out a little script which pipes the login message before stdin to netcat for me.

I was able to get close, but there's one problem I can't figure out. The following script works, in that it sends the login message and allows me to interact with netcat. But if netcat exits (because the server side closed the connection), the script just hangs there (presumably because `cat` is still reading stdin even though no one is reading stdout any more).

```
( echo "${LOGIN}"; cat ) | nc ${HOST} ${PORT}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tricky problem, and you're right about the cause. Processes don't get a NOPIPE error and SIGPIPE until they actually try to write to the pipe.

If nothing else, you can use the interaction scripting tool `expect`:

```
expect <(echo '
    spawn nc google.com 80
    send "GET / HTTP/1.0\n"
    send "Host: www.google.com\n"
    interact
')
```

This will run `nc`, send some HTTP headers, and then gives control to you. When nc exits, so does the command.